# Performance of too many app parts in SharePoint 2013 intranet homepage?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, iframe, app-part

In my company, we have 1500 people using our sharepoint 2013 intranet. My home page, which everyone visits on new tab or IE startup, I am planning on putting about 5-7 app parts. I want to know what would be the performance? I think each app part loads an iframe, and iframes are slow.

Is it worth putting app parts, or should I just directly reference the js/css/html stuff in the home page hardcoded style.

Did anyone deal with this, and know how to handle it?

Thanks

Comment: Here's the opinion of a well-respected SharePoint expert on app parts: http://blah.winsmarts.com/2015-4-AppParts_suck.aspx

Comment: As per my experience i would suggest you to directly use the reference of js, html, txt etc etc. These things are more faster as compared to App part because of the following reason

1) App part loading takes more time as compared to others defined above.
2) App part resides in separate IFrame :( which will irritate you sometimes to do simple operation within that.
3) And here your are talking about 5-7 app parts in single page, Imagine your page will always show "Loading", "Loading " ;)